# Get class name from extended class

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to get the name of the top level class from an extended class, without setting it from the top level class. See example below, I would like to get 'Foo' from Base. I know I could set a variable from Foo, but hoping to skip the extra step.

Thanks.

```
class Base {

    function __construct() {

        echo '<p>get_class: '.get_class().'</p>';
        echo '<p>__CLASS__: '.__CLASS__.'</p>';

    }

}


class Foo extends Base {

}


$test = new Foo();
```

(PHP 5.2.4+)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use:

```
get_class($this);
```

Comment: Don't know who to credit this to. So I will pick the first one with the answer.

Answer (score 32):

[`get_called_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php) for static classes or [`get_class($this)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) for instantiated.

`get_called_class()`, as Jason said, was introduced in PHP 5.3

Comment: `get_called_class()` is only available since 5.3

Comment: Since PHP 5.5, you can use `static::class` instead of `get_called_class()` and `get_class($this)`.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use:

```
get_class($this);
```