# Getting the class name of the constructing class

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get class name from extended class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214655/get-class-name-from-extended-class)

Suppose I have the following:

```
class Foo
{
  public $name;

  public __construct()
  {
    $this->name = __CLASS__;
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
}

class FooBar extends Foo
{
}

$bar = new Bar();
echo $bar->name; // will output 'Foo', but I want 'Bar'

$foobar = new FooBar();
echo $foobar->name; // will output 'Foo', but I want 'FooBar'
```

Is there a way to get the name of the constructing class, without setting the name in a extended class e.g. setting the name in class Foo?

Note: I have a lot of classed derived from Foo, setting the name in every derived class would be a lot of coding.

Comment: What about `get_class()` and all the other associated fctns?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->name = get_class($this);
}
```

http://php.net/get_class

Answer (score 3):

This is very easy: just use [`get_called_class`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-called-class.php):

```
$this->name = get_called_class();
```

This is part of the late static binding features introduced in PHP 5.3. It refers to the class called, rather than the class where the method is defined.

Comment: Probably no need for that (and for a dependency on >=5.3 either), as `__construct` is not truly a static method (it has access to `$this`)

Answer (score 0):

There is a build in php function to get the class name [get_class()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php)

```
$fooBar = new FooBar();
echo get_class($fooBar); //will output FooBar
```